# Why is there a small gap between an absolutely positioned child and parent with borders? All margins, padding, and positions are set to 0

Tags: html, css, css-position

I recreated a stripped down version of the *phenomenon* I'm facing. So the parent has `position: relative` and the `::after` child has `position: absolute` with all directional values set to zero. This would normally stretch out the child directly over the parent perfectly in my experience. Also `* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` is set to be safe and make sure this isn't a `margin` or `padding` issue.

I know I can just set the child element `-1px` left and up... but I'm kind of curious to why this is happening if the child is stretched out directly over it's parent? Is there a way to make it work with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` set to 0?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 5rem; /* to push div closer to center of snippet window */
}
div {
  transform: scale( 5 ); /* added so displacement can be easily seen */
}
div, div::after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  border-color: #666;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  content: '';
}
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Notice from the snippet ( In Chrome atleast ) The `div's` are offset from each other by about 1 px.

**Picture of what I'm seeing in Chrome on desktop:**

[image]

Why aren't these div's placed directly on top of each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference is the `padding-box` and not the `border-box`

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
> ... the containing block is formed by **the padding edge of the ancestor.** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)</sup>

Then *the values are over-constrained* since you are defining `left`/`right`/`width` and the width is equal to the parent (containing block) width so the `right` will be ignored (use any value for it and nothing will happen)

> If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)</sup>

Same logic with `top`/`bottom`/`height` where the `bottom` is ignored.

If you replace your border with a `box-shadow` for example you will have a perfect overlap:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 5rem; /* to push div closer to center of snippet window */
}
div {
  transform: scale( 5 ); /* added so displacement can be easily seen */
}
div, div::after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 0.1rem #666;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  content: '';
}
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: So this behavior is normal? I don't think I've had this issue in the past when stretching absolutely positioned children over their parents

Comment: @devsandbox probably you never had borders. This behavior is quite old and clearly defined in the Spec

Comment: @devsandbox added more details

Comment: You're right. Usually I don't have borders on my elements like this. And removing them seems to fix the problem... smh...weird at the least